# swiftUI how to have search button on keyboard

Tags: swift, button, keyboard, swiftui, textfield

In `SwiftUI` I have a simple search `TextField` where the user type something to be searched and a Button search.

I just want to add the option to have the button Search in the lower right corner of the `Keyboard` (I saw it in some application)

how can I do that?

Comment: might help you https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119794#371283

Comment: maybe you can use .keyboardType(.webSearch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to change the `UIReturnKeyType`.
In that case you have to use **UIKit** since there isn't yet any option to change the type of return key in **SwiftUI**.
To do this, you have to make a custom TextField using UIIKit and then modify it the way you like.

Also keep in mind that the `UIReturnKeyType` enum is under discussion and may replace with a different implementation.

```
// MARK: Custom TextField
struct TextFieldTyped: UIViewRepresentable {
    let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
    let returnVal: UIReturnKeyType
    let tag: Int
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isfocusAble: [Bool]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.keyboardType = self.keyboardType
        textField.returnKeyType = self.returnVal
        textField.tag = self.tag
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        if isfocusAble[tag] {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: TextFieldTyped

        init(_ textField: TextFieldTyped) {
            self.parent = textField
        }

        func updatefocus(textfield: UITextField) {
            textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            if parent.tag == 0 {
                parent.isfocusAble = [false, true]
                parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
            } else if parent.tag == 1 {
                parent.isfocusAble = [false, false]
                parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
         }
        return true
        }

    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:
(Change the `returnVal` to `.search` in your case.)

```
struct CustomeKT: View {

    @State var myTextForTX = ""
    @State var focused: [Bool] = [false, true]

    var body: some View {
        TextFieldTyped(keyboardType: .default, returnVal: .search, tag: 0, text: self.$myTextForTX, isfocusAble: self.$focused)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

## iOS 15

You can change the return key for each `textField` with a simple modifier called: `.submitLabel` that takes the return key type and you should pass `.search`. Take a look  at the  following example:

[image]

Also, as you can see, you can have a callback to handle the return key press action just like the old `textFieldShouldReturn` function that is accessible by '.onSubmit' modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Use SearchTextField.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class UIKitTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        delegate = self
    }
    
    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        delegate = self
        self.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    }
    
    var action:(() -> Void)? = nil
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.action?()
        
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true;
        }
        return false
    }
    
}

struct SearchTextField : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    var action:() -> Void
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(value: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject,UITextFieldDelegate {
        
        var parent:SearchTextField
        
        init(value: SearchTextField) {
            self.parent = value
        }
        
        @objc func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UIKitTextField) {
            self.parent.text = sender.text ?? ""
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIKitTextField {
        
        let textfield = UIKitTextField(frame: .zero)
        
        textfield.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        textfield.text = self.text
        textfield.placeholder = "search"
        textfield.borderStyle = .none
        textfield.returnKeyType = .search
        textfield.action = self.action
        
        return textfield
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIKitTextField,
                      context: Context) {
        uiView.text = self.text
    }
    
}
```

Use :

```
  SearchTextField(text: self.$searchKey) {
      self.search(key: self.searchKey)
      // or...
   }
```